# async await, AsyncStroage puzzle

Tags: react-native

Puzzle is why `console.log('<><><>'+ca(nameToStore));` prints object Object when ca function alerts real name value. Code is as follows:

`

```
    _storeData = async (value) => {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(
                'Key', 
                 value
            );
        } catch (error) {
            alert('Err: ', error);
        }
    }


   async function _getData()  {
        try {
            const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Key');
            if(value !== null) {
                console.log(value);
                return value;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            alert('Err: ', error);
        }
    }

    async function ca (nameToStore) {
        var data = await _getData();
        alert(data);
        return (data);
    }


   function PaymentScreen({route, navigation}) {
    const {it} = route.params;
    const nameToStore = it.name.first;
    _storeData(nameToStore);
    console.log('<><><>'+ca(nameToStore));
......
....
```

How can I get real value in calling function PaymentScreen ?

Answer (score 0):

Async function always return a **promise**, which is an object.

If you would like to call async function when screen on load, use `.then`.

```
function PaymentScreen({route, navigation}) {
    const {it} = route.params;
    const nameToStore = it.name.first;
    _storeData(nameToStore);
    ca(nameToStore).then((data) => {
      //use value returns by promise
      console.log('<><><>' + data);
    });
    ...
}
```